# Calculate the order of the uploaded images in a predifined number of boxes

Tags: javascript

I need some help/guidance to calculate the order of uploaded images.

[image]

I have 4 boxes available(not 2 as in image), in each box an user can upload an image.

I know the boxes order (index) when there are rendered as html.

1. the user doesn't need to upload the images in order, so he can upload an image to box2 and an image to box4

   - so `the box2 -order 0; box4 - order 2`
2. The boxes can also have image initial(in case of update). The user can remove and later replace or not an image

For example:

There are images in all 4 boxes. The user remove the image from box1, box2 and box 3, so

```
box4- order 0
```

Later the user add/replace an image in box3, so:

```
box3 -oder0, box4 -order1
```

I need a starting idea/code in pure javascript.

Comment: no clue exactly what you are asking for. So you want to basically log what elements the user interacted with and keep track of it?

Comment: I uploaded an images in the question to be visual, I want to track the number of images uploaded by the user, and in which order(in which box)

Comment: onchange, check if there is a value, if yes, push the name/id to an array. If there is no value, remove it from the array if it exists

Comment: Hide all boxes. Then, if a box contains an image display it.

Comment: @epascarelo this tells me in which box was added/or removed not the order, in this case every time something is modified I need to change the other

Comment: @cameraman I can't, I need to respect the design

Comment: How does the user upload a new image?  Do they click the image they want to upload to, or is there a button underneath each image?

Comment: there is a hidden input, and the image is set as the label of the input

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the empty boxes have to be always at the end of the line and ordered by their index.

The full boxes have to be in-front and ordered by the last user interaction.

The following lines calculate the order of each box. You need to set the "isEmpty" and "updated" values.

The "updated" value is the date of the last interaction and has to be 0 if the box is empty.

```js
var order = 0;
var emptyBoxes = [];
var fullBoxes = [];
var boxes = [
  {index:0, order:0, isEmpty:true, updated:0},
  {index:1, order:0, isEmpty:true, updated:0},
  {index:2, order:0, isEmpty:false, updated:1519211810362},
  {index:3, order:0, isEmpty:false, updated:1519211809934}
];

boxes.forEach (function(box){  
  if(box.isEmpty){
    emptyBoxes.push(box.index);
  }else{
    fullBoxes.push({index:box.index,updated:box.updated});     
  }
});

fullBoxes.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.updated - b.updated;
});

fullBoxes.forEach (function(box){
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(boxes[i].index == box.index){
      boxes[i].order = order;
      order++;
    } 
  }
});

emptyBoxes.forEach (function(boxIndex){
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if(boxes[i].index == boxIndex){
      boxes[i].order = order;
      order++;
    } 
  }
});


boxes.forEach (function(box){
  console.log("the order for box #"+box.index+" is "+box.order); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send current timestamp with the image . The moment user clicks upload image update image and timestamp and then at backend you can easily sort out which order the user uploaded images.

Comment: if user add an image in the third(3) box first and later in box1, and box4, the timestamp will not work; the timestamp tells me the order of uploads and not the order in boxes

Comment: So on every upload button press create a object with object.create and set configurable and writable property to false and send that object with the image.